# How to return list of ID-s with Django Rest framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

With this type of serializer, I got as an ID value inside the post object of the id of the user that made the post but I want a list of users that liked the post. Following Django documentation, I think that it should look like this but apparently, something is wrong.

```
User = get_user_model()

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer):
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email' ]


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectPost
        fields = ['id',
                ...
                'published',]


class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ['id']

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    project = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'student', 'project', 'likes']
        
    def get_like(self, obj):
        return LikeSerializer(obj).data
    
    def get_student(self, obj):
        return StudentSerializer(obj.student).data

    def get_project(self, obj):
        return ProjectSerializer(obj.project).data
```

And here are my Models

```
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name="student")
    project = models.OneToOneField(ProjectPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    #bookmark = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='bookmark')

    def get_student(self):
        return self.student.name


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_user(self):
        print(self.user.id, 'aaa')
        return self.user.id
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of user IDs that liked a post, in PostSerializer you could use another SerializerMethodField like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users_liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    

def get_users_liked(self, obj):
    return obj.like_set.all().values_list("user__id", flat=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

As per the docs:

> PrimaryKeyRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the
> relationship using its primary key.
>
> For example, the following serializer:
>
> ```
> class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>     tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = Album
>         fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
> ```
>
> Would serialize to a representation like this:
>
> ```
> {
>     'album_name': 'Undun',
>     'artist': 'The Roots',
>     'tracks': [
>         89,
>         90,
>         91,
>         ...
>     ]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a reverse relationship. Since you didn't specify a `related_name` on the `Like` model, you need to add `like_set` to your fields list. If you specify a `related_name="likes"` then you would just have to add `likes` without the `SerializerMethodField`. If you are unsure of what attributes you have access to, try importing the `Like` model into a `python manage.py shell` and run `dir(Like)`. This should show you all the things.

Comment: I did exactly that and know it works but the only problem is now I get the id of like object and not the id of the user inside that object, and thanks

Comment: Right, good point, my bad, I missed the "user id" part of your question. In that case, yes you would need a SerializerMethodField just like @Igor has. :)  One thing we use is a nifty package that allows you to expand your relationship fields. It solved a lot of headache for us. Check it out: https://pypi.org/project/drf-flex-fields/

Comment: Thank you very much